# Folders are not synchronized in Vagrant box

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtual-machine

Vagrant stopped synchronising my folders. **Homestead.yaml** maps folders like this:

```
folders:
- map: ~/my-folder
  to: /home/vagrant/my-folder
```

1. I listed all boxes and removed all existing ones.
2. I re-installed the one I need:

   vagrant init laravel/homestead

After the installation, when I **vagrant up**:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' version '12.0.0' is up to date...
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
```

I also called **vagrant provision** but no luck. I can login:

```
vagrant ssh
```

But folders are not there. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long struggle, I found an answer to my problem. After halting and removing boxes, I also removed the content under:

```
/.vagrant.d/boxes
```

...and than, I re-installed Homestead folder from stretch, added

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead
```

...and than when I vagrant up, Code folder started synchronizing.

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

Comment: I tried but no chance.